# In Stripe API Promotional Code, does the customer field relates to a customer that can use the code or is it limiting the code to that customer?

Tags: promotion-code, stripe-payments

https://stripe.com/docs/api/promotion_codes/object?lang=node#promotion_code_object-customer

This. Is it for when creating the code so I can limit the code to exactly that customer
or is it when the customer redeems the code, his id is added in there by stripe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found in their docs, it's actually the limit. It limits to a particular customer, who's the only one who can use it. Took me some time so I am answering it here:

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/discounts/codes#limit-by-customer